# spotfire data function: input parameter of table do not include all the columns of the data table

Tags: spotfire

In spotfire R data function, I use table as input, and then when i edit input parameter, I found not all the columns are available for me to add in.
The table in this spotfire dxp file has 15 columns which is created by procedure, but in the input parameter of the table, only 12 columns is shown for me to add.
So I can quite confused...how to solve the problem 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jch0O.png)

Update:I found the root cause, spotfire do not support longinteger type as input column

Comment: Can you give us the complete table definition?

Comment: in 'type' dropdown of input parameter setting, there are three options(value,column,table), here select table

Comment: Somne actual code would be helpful.

Comment: thanks Markus, i have found the root cause as updated in description